# how to add Interstitial AdMob out MainActivity in other Class without the Method onCreate?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, interstitial

I am a beginner in Java.
I had Android games that I open on Eclipse and Android Studio.
When I want to add the MainActivity class that does not contain the onCreate method as the Normal Classes of the Games Example: Pause - Menu ..., still the current object new InterstitialAd (this); Is underlined by the red color.

Can I get help please ?
Here is all the data to bring to my source code.

```
//Class PauseLayer :

import com.exemplapp.myapptetest.RacingActivity;
import com.exemplapp.myapptetest.scene.GameScene;
import com.exemplapp.myapptetest.scene.TitleScene;
import com.exemplapp.nodes.GrowButton;
import com.exemplapp.nodes.MyScene;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite;
import org.cocos2d.transitions.CCFadeTransition;

public class PauseLayer extends MyScene {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public PauseLayer() {
        super();
        RacingActivity activity = (RacingActivity) CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
        activity.revmob();

        CCSprite sprBg = CCSprite.sprite(PATH_BG + "pause_bg-ipad.png");
        this.addChild(sprBg);
        sprBg.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

        GrowButton btnResume = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
                + "btnResume-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnResume-ipad.png",
                this, "onResume");
        this.addChild(btnResume);
        btnResume.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 260 * 32 / 15);

        GrowButton btnReplay = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
                + "btnReplay-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnReplay-ipad.png",
                this, "onReplay");
        this.addChild(btnReplay);
        btnReplay.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 220 * 32 / 15);

        GrowButton btnMenu = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
                + "btnMenu1-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnMenu1-ipad.png", this,
                "onMenu");
        this.addChild(btnMenu);
        btnMenu.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 180 * 32 / 15);


//Admon Interstitial

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);

        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });


    }

    private void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }


    public void onResume(Object sender) {
        this.removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    }

    public void onReplay(Object sender) {
        CCDirector
                .sharedDirector()
                .replaceScene(
                        CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, GameScene
                                .scene(GameScene.sharedInstance().m_nGameMode)));
    }

    public void onMenu(Object sender) {
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(
                CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, TitleScene.scene()));
    }
}

//Certificate of AndroidManifest :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.exemplapp.myapptetest.RacingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sling_shot_racing"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.exemplapp.myapptetest.scene.game.PauseLayer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interstitial ads method in pass context or activity for object creation.

that mean we can pass then context or activity

you can write like this

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
```

where activity is RacingActivity that was was declare above final code look like

```
  public PauseLayer() {
     super();
     RacingActivity activity = (RacingActivity) CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
     activity.revmob();

    CCSprite sprBg = CCSprite.sprite(PATH_BG + "pause_bg-ipad.png");
    this.addChild(sprBg);
    sprBg.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

    GrowButton btnResume = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
            + "btnResume-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnResume-ipad.png",
            this, "onResume");
    this.addChild(btnResume);
    btnResume.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 260 * 32 / 15);

    GrowButton btnReplay = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
            + "btnReplay-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnReplay-ipad.png",
            this, "onReplay");
    this.addChild(btnReplay);
    btnReplay.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 220 * 32 / 15);

    GrowButton btnMenu = GrowButton.buttonWithSpriteFileName(PATH_BTN
            + "btnMenu1-ipad.png", PATH_BTN + "btnMenu1-ipad.png", this,
            "onMenu");
    this.addChild(btnMenu);
    btnMenu.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 180 * 32 / 15);


   //Admon Interstitial

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);

    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });


 }
```

Comment: yes Thanks for the reply, I changed (this); with (activity); 
but the button Game Pause it does not work any more.
what's your idea ?

Comment: you can try debugging to watch what can happen it can help https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: whatever i'm looking in every place official but not solution.
the Pub of Revmob and Applovin they working good but Admob not.
also i'm delete all certificate and content of Applovin and Revmob, but not solution too.

Comment: which type of language use

Comment: now whats does not work? please short explain in details.